# Anaconda Safety Error: Skip sha256 mismatch and continue

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

I get the following error when trying to install setuptools 39.1.0 which is required for upgrading anaconda

```
SafetyError: The package for setuptools located at F:\Python\Anaconda3\pkgs\setuptools-39.1.0-py36_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'Scripts/easy_install.exe'
has a sha256 mismatch.
  reported sha256: 993203a406e04936a07829b1f482fd27d739b640482e213f4c49ea1ee78a5fcf
  actual sha256: ea8a03c54607998725927caa8e1babd997f0353b6d1ee35a28b154db689642ce
```

I tried with `-f` flag attempting to bypass, but it did not work.

Even weird, when I manually tried to update setuptools, it was successfully updated to `39.2.0`, but unfortunately when I update anaconda, conda wants to downgrade it to `39.1.0` :/

What do I do to install it anyway? Or should I install setuptools from elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to reinstall Anaconda. I could not find an easy and a guaranteed workaround

Answer (score 1):

This problem could occur when you use differents package managers... The solution is removing manually the affected packages and retry it.

The -f flag does not force this problem, and "conda clean -a" or "conda clean --packages" is not a solution because don't remove packages that currently being linked into an environment.

Comment: And unfortunately the affected package as I have mentioned earlier is `setuptools` which can NOT be removed manually without removing conda all by itself